# How to fix joined words problem, after RegEx removes spaces from punctuation?

Tags: php, regex, punctuation

My RegEx code removes spaces from the left and right side of the punctuation inside the string. after removing those spaces, the result is okay but some words have joined together.

I tried to change my RegEx code, but the result is exactly what I wanted, even I tried to test my RegEx on online testing websites like ‍‍‍[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AvooIC/5) and others. the result is okay in there and words won't join together, but in my code, the result is different. I even tried different RegEx codes with different styles for this but still, in my code, some words join together.
BTW, the language of strings is **`Farsi`**. but the method works fine for both.

```php
$text = "سلام ، این یک متن (   است) متشکرم.";
$removePattern = "/(\s+)*([\.\!\:\)\]\}\(\[\{\?\,\;\؟\،\؛])(\s+)*/";
$replace = "$2";
$text = preg_replace($removePattern, $replace, $text);
```

I expect that the output would be
`سلام،این یک متن(است)متشکرم.`

But the result is something like this
`سلاماین یک متنامتحانیاست  (شایداینطوری) بهتر، باشه`

Can you see how `سلاماین` and `متنامتحانیاست` are joined and stick together?
my problem is how I can fix this issue and what is the solution to solve this? this has to work for different strings with different contents for Farsi.

Comment: Copypasted your code to new .php file in PhpStorm, added `echo $text;`, and I get exactly the output you're expecting: `سلام،این یک متن(است)متشکرم.` (this is copied from PhpStorm console, not from your post). So, I guess check your console settings?

Comment: @alx Yes, the result is okay in the console and RegEx testing websites. but when I send the string back with HTTP GET header request, the string is not showing like that.

Comment: I did `php -S localhost:1234` and navigated to `http://localhost:1234/index.php` (my test php file is `index.php`), and I see exactly the same output: `سلام،این یک متن(است)متشکرم.`. Browser encoding was 'Default', which is UTF-8 in this case (checked by forcing it to UTF-8). So, everything seems to be good except your browser: check encoding (maybe force it with HTTP header), check other browser. BTW, I'm using PHP 7.3.3.

Comment: If you work with utf-8 it's good idea to specify `u` flag: ...`(\s+)*/u";`

Answer (score 0):

you may communicate between Linux and Windows Systems.
they handle whitespace characters differently.

anyway

```
"/(\s+)*([\.\!\:\)\]\}\(\[\{\?\,\;\؟\،\؛])(\s+)*/";

change to

"/(\R+)*([\.\!\:\)\]\}\(\[\{\?\,\;\؟\،\؛])(\R+)*/";
```

you will match any whitespace char regardless of the system

Answer (score 0):

You need just twice replace that.
At first replace this regex "[(][ ]*" with ( and second time replace it with "[ ]*[)]" with )